# Bower and Sass in a Rails-like folder structure

Tags: node.js, sass, asset-pipeline, gruntjs, bower

So I'm working on this project that has a Rails-like folder structure though it's handled by Node.js tooling (Grunt as task runner). I'm using Bower to manage my vendor assets.

My folder structure looks like this:

```
  .
  └── src
      ├── app
      │   └── assets
      │       ├── javascripts
      │       └── stylesheets
      │           └── application.scss
      ├── public
      └── vendor
          └── bower
```

Basically all the development source code lives in the `app/assets` folder, `public` is where production files go and `vendor` is where 3rd party stuff goes.

So as you can see, I have this `application.scss` file. This is the stylesheet manifest I'm using. It's responsible to import all the modules that should be compiled to my final stylesheet file later.

The problem is that I don't see a sane way to reference libraries installed through Bower from inside my manifest file.

With Rails Asset Pipeline/Sprockets I would do `//= require_tree vendor/bower` and that would work but I don't know what's the equivalent of doing that on the context of this project.

Do you guys have any suggestion on what could I do?

Ps.: Using Grunt tasks to "handle" this is out of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just configure Bower to install packages on `vendor/assets/components` by creating a file called `.bowerrc` in your root directory.

```
{"directory": "vendor/assets/components"}
```

Everything inside `vendor/assets` and `app/assets` is added to the load path, so you can just reference those files.

You may need to put the actual file you want to load. Let's say you installed the [normalize-scss](https://github.com/appleboy/normalize.scss) package. You'll probably have to add this to your `application.scss` file:

```
@import "normalize-scss/normalize";
```

This is just a guess, but I'd bet on it.

EDIT: This will work on Rails apps, which apparently isn't your case. So if you're using Grunt to compile SCSS, you can add the Bower directory to your load path with the `loadPath` option.

The Gruntfile's Sass task may look with something like this:

```
{
  sass: {
    dist: {
      files: {"src/assets/stylesheets/application.scss": "public/application.css"},
      options: {
        loadPath: ["vendor/bower"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To import the file, you will do something like I said above (referencing the whole file). Didn't test the Grunt configuration, but it'll probably work.

Answer (score 0):

Bower downloads whole git repositories.

Example:

```
bower install jquery
```

This would create the following structure

```
tree vendor/bower 
bower
└── jquery
    ├── bower.json
    ├── component.json
    ├── composer.json
    ├── jquery.js
    ├── jquery-migrate.js
    ├── jquery-migrate.min.js
    ├── jquery.min.js
    ├── jquery.min.map
    ├── package.json
    └── README.md

1 directory, 10 files
```

It doesn't make much sense to load all those files in my opinion.

What You could do is:

- create a `vendor/require` directory
- symlink all required files into this directory:

  ```
  cd vendor/require; ln -s ../bower/jquery/jquery.min.js
  ```
- then require all files with ruby's help or manually

  ```
  Dir['path/to/vendor/require/*.js'].each do |file_name|
    puts "<script type="text/javascript" src="#{file_name}"></script>"
  end
  ```

You could also use Grunt and it's [concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat) task:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  concat: {
    options: {
      separator: ';',
    },
    dist: {
      src: ['path/to/vendor/bower/jquery/jquery.min.js', 'path/to/vendor/bower/other-package/init.min.js'],
      // or if You decide to create those symlinks
      // src: ['path/to/vendor/require/*'],
      dest: 'path/to/public/js/built.js',
    },
  },
});
```

---

For `compass` on `sass` You could use:

```
@import 'path/to/directory/*';
```